# cython check if a cpp set is subset of another cpp set

Tags: python, c++, cython

In Cython, I want to check if a c++ set of ints is a subset of another set of ints.

Basically I am trying to convert some python code into cython. so far, I have the following code:
The python code:

```
    class py_ob:
       def __init__(x, set_x=None):
           self.x =x
           self.set_x =set_x
           #other attributes and functions

    def comp(a, b):
       if a.x<b.x:
          if a.set_x.issubset(b.set_x):
             return True
       else:
             return False
```

In cython :

```
    from libcpp.set cimport set as cpp_set
    from libcpp.algorithm cimport includes
    cdef class ob:
       cdef public int x
       cdef public cpp_set set_x
       
       cdef __init__(int x, cpp_set set_x=None):
           self.x=x
           self.set_x = set_x
    

    cpdef comp (ob a, ob b):
        if a.x<b.x: 
            if includes(a.set_x.begin(), a.set_x.end(), b.set_x.begin(), b.set_x.end()):
                return True
        else :
            return False
```

However I get a lot of errors :

```
'libcpp\algorithm\includes.pxd' not found
Cannot assign None to set[T]
 Cannot convert Python object to 'set[T]'
'includes' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
 Cannot convert 'iterator' to Python object
```

Any idea how to use cpp sets and check if a set is a subset of another set ?

Comment: C++ `set` is templated - it can only hold one type. I wouldn't make it a public attribute - this'll cause an expensive copy to a Python `set` every time you access it. You probably want to type the arguments to `comp` as `ob`. But there's *a lot* wrong with this code - why not just use Python sets?

Comment: @DavidW I will be accessing these sets a lot and adding elements as well as doing some other operations like difference and intersection but I guess the most expensive one is issubset. The reason why I would like to move to cpp sets is that the current performance of the code is bad and after profiling, the function comp is the most expensive so I believe I need better containers than Python sets.

Comment: in my case these sets will only hold ints so it is inline with cpp however I need to initialize with something else than an empty set as I am afraid to use a mutable (ie. set()) in the init function. you said making it public will cause an expensive copy to a Python set evrytime you access it. I believe I need to also move the code that calls this object to cython so that should not be a problem no?

Comment: You know that c++ set has different complexity to Python set for checking if an element is contained in it? You may not find it an improvement. In principle it's definitely paint to do this in Cython though

Comment: you mean that there is not a big performance gain when checking if a set is a subset of another set in c++ vs in python ? and is too much effort?

Comment: Checking if an element is in a C++ set is `O(log n)` while in a Python set it's `O(1)`. Obviously that doesn't tell you anything about the constants though so I don't know if it's worth it